# authentication in mysql8 with docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I've been reading the threads about connecting to a mysql instance running in a Docker container, tried all the magic solutions and none of them seem to work. I have a working PHP app, and phpAdmin works too (both Docker images). From inside PHP, I can connect fine. Now I'm trying to connect using a vanilla Node.js example server, and the connection keeps getting refused. It started with an errno -4078 until I used tcp-connect, and now it became an errno 1045 (access denied). I'm starting mysql like this:

```
docker run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=TRUE --expose 3306 -p 3036:3036 mysql
```

and the app either using 'node app.js' directly, or with Docker (after using docker build) like this

```
docker run --name app -d --link mysql:db -p 8081:8080 app
```

I'm starting the working PHP app in exactly the same way, no difference - and it works, but Node doesn't. The same user and password combination lets me log in manually using the mysql CLI in a bash shell, so the password is okay.

The Dockerfile is as vanilla as it gets, like this:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

It's mysql version 8.1.0 and Docker version 24.0.5

There are two users that work in phpMyAdmin: the root user with no password, and another user with a password and all privileges. I'm trying to connect from the outside into a Docker container, so I exposed port 3306 (which seems to work), and the 'link' directive seems to work when starting the app, it's apparently "trying" to connect. Nothing dies, it just says "connection refused". I tried the environment variable solutions, i tried the tcp-connect, I tried the mysql_native_password and none of these solutions are doing the trick. What am I doing wrong?

ps oh and, can I go the other way, and instead of trying to bypass security, just give it what it wants? (I don't know that that is, a certificate? A key pair or something?)

I expected that the same thing that works in PHP should work in Node, but that's apparently not the case. What is PHP doing differently? (The PHP is in a Docker image running Alpine Nginx, it's a pretty vanilla PHP app, just shows a few pages with some database content).

EDIT: The answer referenced by the moderators absolutely does NOT answer the question. First of all it references a config that doesn't exist in MySql 8, and secondly THERE IS NO BIND STATEMENT in the new v8 config file. And thirdly the configs aren't even in the same place. And fourthly the recommend answer didn't even appear in the "similar questions" list. Please reopen this question for further assistance.

Answer (score -1):

To authenticate to MySQL 8 in Docker, you can use the following steps:

1. **Start a MySQL 8 container with the `mysql_native_password` authentication plugin enabled.**

This can be done by passing the `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` flag to the `docker run` command. For example, the following command will start a MySQL 8 container with the `mysql_native_password` authentication plugin enabled:

docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_80 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:8 mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

2. **Connect to the MySQL 8 container using a MySQL client.**

You can use any MySQL client to connect to the container, such as the MySQL CLI or MySQL Workbench. When connecting, be sure to use the `root` user and the password that you specified when starting the container.

For example, to connect to the MySQL 8 container using the MySQL CLI, you would use the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

When prompted, enter the password that you specified when starting the container.

Once you are connected, you can use the MySQL client to issue commands to the MySQL server. For example, to create a new database, you would use the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
```

**Note:** If you are using a MySQL client that does not support the `caching_sha2_password` authentication plugin, you will need to use the `mysql_native_password` authentication plugin instead. To do this, you can specify the `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` flag when connecting to the MySQL server.

**Example:**

```
mysql -u root -p --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password -h localhost -P 3306
```

**Security considerations:**

- Be sure to use a strong password for the MySQL root user.
- Consider using a different user account for everyday use, and only use the root user when necessary.
- Keep your MySQL software up to date with the latest security patches.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with connection refused error. GenAI generated content is not allowed on SO.